# Whats H9DA4GH2GJBM chip used for?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have been investigating counterfeit devices and how they work. I noticed that this one USB device claimed to have 8GB doesnt seem to be telling the truth as it corrupts around 200mb, I opened the usb to investigate and i found this Chip (seems like a storage chip) And i need help what does it do.

[image]
[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFvGF.jpg)

Comment: Not much info online, at least in English.  I found this link that claims a datasheet is available for download on request, but I couldn't figure out how you request it.  https://www.datasheeticpdf.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=H9DA4GH2GJBM

Comment: Counterfeit USB sticks usually use a normal chip that would be inside a normal USB stick, but either the memory on that chip is defective, or there is only a smaller memory amount in the first, but the microcontroller is reprogrammed to pretend being a stick with a larger size. The serial number on the chip may or may not be real, depending on how it is produced.

Comment: Looks like a regular eMMC flash chip made by Hynix, a pretty common one.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, do you happen to know what the capacity of that chip is supposed to be?

Comment: What is on the other side of the board?

Comment: It is just a black circle, This part heats up quickly upon plugging. Probably just the circuit connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found it, at least very similar. It seems to be made by Hynix or one of their affiliates. The index "9" belongs to category ["multi-chip package".](https://www.skhynix.com/eng/product/multiPackage.jsp) per Hynix classification. It seems like the part "9HDA4" is a combination of [4Gb (256Mb x16) NAND Flash with 4Gb (2*64Mb x32 2CS 2CKE) DDR](https://datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/Hynix/H9DA4GH4JJAMCR/pdf.php?id=731335). Full datasheet in English is linked from there.

The DDR must be used as a fast buffer I guess, to speed up transfers of short files. Looks like the DDR is only 2Gbit in the H9DA4GH2GJBM part. The IC seems to be obsolete, so no actual datasheet can be found on the main SKhynix website.

[image]

So the entire device can't be bigger than 512 MB in size. Definitely not 8GB.

Comment: So it is intended for temporary high speed cache rather than a Memory stick?

Comment: @Android_Helper, not really, in this case it is intended for a memory stick with improved performance on short files.