# can't format 128gb SD card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, diskpart

I am trying to format my SD card which is 128gig and pretty sure that the card reader works. however my SD card is being read but it's showing only 30mb available. So I tried formatting it using Ease Us partition and then tried diskpart.

[image: DiskPart]

[image: Select Partition 1]

Comment: Either the card reader doesn't work, or the card's not 128G, or both are broken...

Comment: There are counterfeit SD cards, just like there are counterfeit USB flash drives. https://superuser.com/questions/1380180/whats-h9da4gh2gjbm-chip-used-for